# How do you make a fold expression with custom operator <<?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to make a print function based on parameter pack and fold expression. My implementation fails to compile on clang 10.0. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const std::set<int> &set) {
  strm << set.size();
  return strm;
}

template <typename... Args> void Print(std::ostream &strm, Args &&... args) {
  (strm << ... << args);
}

int main(int, char **) {
  std::set<int> my_set;
  Print(std::cout, my_set);
}
```

and here is the compiler output

```
#1 with x86-64 clang 10.0.0
<source>:10:12: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup

  (strm << ... << args);

           ^

<source>:15:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Print<std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > &>' requested here

  Print(std::cout, my_set);

  ^

<source>:4:15: note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const std::set<int> &set) {

              ^

1 error generated.

Compiler returned: 1
```

The same code compiles with gcc 10.1. Is this a compiler bug (or missing feature), or is my implementation incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Argument-dependent lookup is not helping you here.
The error message is:

> :10:12: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup

So it's looking for an `operator<<` to call:

- It looks in the definition of `std::set` - nope, none there.
- It looks in namespace `std` (because that's where `std::set` lives) - nope, not there, either.

Should it look in the global namespace? I don't know.

Clearly gcc and clang have different opinions about that.

Comment: That's right, defining `operator <<` in namespace `std` fixes the compiler error

Comment: Yes, but technically you're not allowed to do that, because neither of the types involved (`std::ostream` or `std::set`) are user-defined (i.e, yours)

Comment: Why shouldn’t it be found by ordinary unqualified lookup from the template definition?